# Bootstrap modal box

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I used bootstrap class in my project.
This my html code:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">رویدادها</h3>
    </div>
    <table id="tbl-events" class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>title</th>
                <th>startTime</th>
                <th>endTime</th>
                <th>Imae</th>
                <th>description</th>
                <th class="action"></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Title</td>
                    <td>@(new PersianDateTime(item.StartTime).ToDateString())</td>
                    <td>@(new PersianDateTime(item.EndTime).ToDateString())</td>
                    <td class="event-img"><img src="@(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Picture) ? "/images/nopic.png" : path + item.Picture)" alt="[Picture]" width="30" height="30" /></td>
                    <td class="event-desctript"><span>@item.Description</span></td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/admin/event/edit/@item.ID"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i></a>
                        <a href="/admin/event/delete/@item.ID" onclick="alert()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Do you want to save changes you made to document before closing?</p>
                    <p class="text-warning"><small>If you don't save, your changes will be lost.</small></p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this my js code:

```
function confirm_delete() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
}
```

when I click on `<a href="/admin/event/delete/@item.ID" onclick="confirm_delete()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></a>` page reload and item removed from list and dialog don't show for ok or canceling delete!
How I can handle this problem?

Comment: Please add some more information about the expected behavior and where it fails

Comment: When I click on above link I want show dialog modal and when user select ok delete item but in my code don't show modal and but delete item! how I can fix it